# Getting a USB Device Instance Path in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a USB device with VID=XXXX and PID=YYYY attached. I'd like to get the end of the Device Instance Path using powershell. For example, if the actual path is `USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY\001122334455` then I want `001122334455`.

I was trying something like this just to get the device properties, but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnPEntity -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Filter "PNPDeviceID='USB\\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY'" |Format-List *
```

Can anybody suggest the correct way to get the value I'm looking for through Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LIKE` instead of `=` in your `Filter`, like so:

`(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnPEntity -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Filter "PNPDeviceID like 'USB\\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX%'").PNPDeviceID.Substring(22)`